# Leverage points in linear regression

Tags: statistics, numerical-linear-algebra, linear-regression

From the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leverage_(statistics)), leverage of a point is defined as the measure of how far away the independent variable values of an observation are from those of the other observations. Mathematically for point(observation) $x_i$, it is given by $h_{ii}=x_i^T(X^TX)^{-1}x_i$, where rows of matrix $X \in R^{n*d}$ contains points. Now my question is how does the formula leads to the interpretation given in first line. This is how I see it, If we calculate the covariance matrix from the observation to find mahalanobis type distance metric we have covariance as $(X^TX-\frac{1}{n^2}X^T \mathbf{1} X)$, ( note rows of X are our points) where $\mu^T=\frac{1}{n}[1,1...,1]X$ and $\mathbf{1} \in R^{n*n}$ is matrix of all $1$'s. And now if we use this as distance metric shouldn't the leverage be defined as $\hat{h_{ii}}=(x_i-\mu)^T(X^TX-\frac{1}{n^2}X^T \mathbf{1} X)^{-1}(x_i-\mu)$ ? How does one come up with the interpretation?

Also I am curious what properties of colspace of $X$ does leverage score(leverage of each point) help us understand? Any help, comments, hints are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @zen Are you sure (here and in your answer) you're not mixing influential points with high leverage points? Maybe [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65912/precise-meaning-of-and-comparison-between-influential-point-high-leverage-point) gives some explanation

Comment: A high leverage point really is one that is far from the 'center' of the data. I think the term comes from the similarity with the physical lever, points far from the fulcrum have more leverage than those near it. However, a point that has high leverage need not be influential (e.g. if it lies on the regression line).

Comment: @Blaza you are correct I confused the terms it seems. I will delete those comments but leave this one up.

Comment: @Blaza part of the answer is still correct so I will modify that instead of deleting. I must not have been very sharp when I wrote either because when I read it back I jump from the correct interpretation to the wrong interpretation constantly. The LS part is still correct though and the last few lines as well.

Comment: I think that you question was almost fully answered on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/199686/prove-the-relation-between-mahalanobis-distance-and-leverage)

Comment: I am going to delete my answer in favor of the better and more complete answer at cross validated that @Blaza linked to